# Lead developer unable to do INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, teamwork

I had worked in the past for a small company developing web applications. Back then the <del>current</del> lead developer, who is also one of the bosses, told me that he is incapable of making a `JOIN` inside a `SQL` query.

I was amazed how a person who has developed and maintain big ecommerce site is incapable of doing that.

Are database normalization and functional dependencies a waste of time? Are they only necessary in big demanding projects?

Comment: Congratulation, you just discovered that you are stuck with a boss who is technically unqualified and doesn't realize it. You might want to consult http://workplace.stackexchange.com for tipps how to deal with this situation.

Comment: Talking to the current lead developer at a company you worked at in the past probably means he didn't work under this manager or he would have seen the poor coding first-hand and could answer this question for himself.

Comment: Maybe the "current" part was misleading.

Comment: If I was doing a mailing list for the bowling team, I'd be using Inner Joins, this is like asking if you need gasoline to run a car. Most of the time the answer is yes, unless it runs on electricity or diesel. You could live without it, but why not just learn it.

Comment: To make a lot of money in the software industry, you don't have to be a great developer, but a great salesman who understands what the clients want. If you've got that quality then even if you're not a good  developer, you can run a succesful business. If all you are is a rock star developer, then I hope you find a good boss.

Comment: Database normalization is a strategy, not a commandment. There are cases where it makes sense to normalize, and cases where it does not. Furthermore, the rise of NoSQL is going to create a caste of devs in a few years whom do not posses the basic SQL skills that we all take as part of a standard developer's repertoire. In all likelihood, the dev in question is probably just a crappy dev, but nonetheless, there will be plenty of great developers whom do not do much SQL JOINing in the very near future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Joining tables is the bread and butter of using relational databases. When you can't do JOINs, you don't really understand them. That's why any good database course usually starts with drawing ERD diagrams before even writing the first line of SQL.

Object-oriented design patterns are often dismissed by people who use them every day, but lack the ability to recognize them. But being able to recognize and use them allows one to read and write a lot more elegant and modular OO code.

You wonder how someone can still write a sufficiently complex and successful application using both relational databases and an object-oriented programming language without understanding these things? It is surprising how far you can get in software development without really knowing what you are doing when you are just persistent enough. You don't know JOINs? No problem, you just select everything from both tables and write a matching-algorithm in the application. It will take five times as much development time, will be ten times slower and have twenty times the amount of sourcecode than just writing a JOIN, but in the end you have the data you want. And you are proud of yourself, because you couldn't imagine a better way to solve this complex problem. When your only tool is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

In fact *writing* a large, feature-complete application isn't the difficult part. The difficult part is *maintaining* it.

The difference between good and bad code usually isn't that notable during the development phase of a product. I would even argue that an unskilled development team might bring a product to market *even quicker*, because they tend to overlook some hidden complexity which won't be noticed without proper Test and QA management (they will be noticed after the product is in production - which will usually be worse).

But software quality starts to matter after the product goes from the development-phase into the support-phase and unexpected changes need to be made to the code base. A well thought-out code base written by a skilled and experienced software architect is a lot more flexible than one hacked together by a beginner, which means that modifying the application after release will be a lot easier and thus cheaper. And the worse the initial development team, the more bugs and missing features will need to be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Database normalization and functional dependencies are *crucial in the smallest of applications.*

If you doubt this, just consider a simple Address Book application.

[image]

Already you have five normalized tables, and four relations.

Oh sure, you can go the way of NoSQL and do everything with simple Key/Value pairs, but as long as you are using a relational database, why not use the capabilities that such a platform provides?

Normalization provides a number of important benefits, including the removal of data duplication, and the convenience and power that set theory computations provide.  Users of Key/Value systems understand this the first time they try to write a report.

Comment: Hmm. A lot of applications nowadays use APIs to access other people's data.

Comment: Why is that relevant?

Comment: Because database normalization is entirely irrelevant in those cases, no matter how big or small the application. Likewise if you have a DBA and communicate with the DB through Sprocs. I'm ok with databases but I've gone entire periods of my career without touching one.

Comment: So you're going to never learn relations because you get all of your data in Key/Value pairs from some magic black box over the Internet?  It wouldn't be true anyway, because you can represent complex data structures (including relations) in objects handed to you over the Internet.  So you're still going to need some basic understanding.

Comment: No, but I think someone can certainly get by without knowing how to write a SQL join, which is all the OP's lead actually said.

Comment: That's true @pdr s comment explains a lot.

Comment: @yannis: If you don't know how to do a join, you don't have a working knowledge of SQL at all.  I don't know how you can really call yourself a developer without such knowledge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What I meant is the big ecommerce site that my boss is developed/maintented it retrieves data from APIs.

Comment: @yannis: And that, to me, sounds a lot like "How can you call yourself a musician if you can't play piano?"

Comment: Your design has 5 tables and 4 relations, but you could have a design with just one table with customer, phone, and address columns on one row.  Every new customer new address or phone is a new record.  One table, no joins.  Now there would be a lot of nulls and lots of chances to insert poor quality data and potentially data repeats, but it's a workable.  So, I wouldn't call it crucial in small applications, but it's definately important and leads to better (maintainable and sound) software and underlying code.

Comment: @pdr I am missing your point? Plenty of musicians around that can't play the piano and are very, very, very accomplished if not famous musicians.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I think #pdr is claiming the exactly same thing. He is just being sarcastic.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: Correct. That's exactly my point. You can be a musician without ever knowing how to play piano, you can be a sportsman without learning to pole-vault, and you can be a developer without writing a SQL query. Anyone who claims otherwise is being a snob, choosing definitions of development that legitimise themselves as more of a developer than someone else. Like a piano player suggesting that a drummer isn't a real musician.

Comment: Learning how to play the piano and learning what a JOIN is are not quite the same thing.  They're not even in the same league.  If a developer doesn't have enough intellectual curiosity to even learn what a simple JOIN is, then what's the hope of them ever learning anything more substantial, like a Continuation?

Comment: @pdr Usually better at picking up sarcasm when I read it :) thanks for responding. I wholeheartedly agree with your response to my question!

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You are assuming too much. Namely that you cannot be a developer without having to deal with relational data or a query language. You can. Many are. Doesn't detract one little bit of their developer-ness. Heck, I only know what a JOIN is because of my earlier work. Haven't touched a database or a SQL statement in my work for more than 9 years. Doesn't make me less of a developer. In fact, in those years I have grown more as a developer than in many of the years I did work with SQL JOINs.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: I totally never said that you couldn't *be* a developer and not know JOIN.  And you yourself pointed out that you do know what a JOIN is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, but you are making judgements about people you don't know and their level of competency or developer-ness based on knowing or not knowing a single aspect of programming which isn't exactly as ubiquitous as you may think.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't see how learning to play the piano and learning to do SQL queries aren't comparable.  Many musicians learn to play the piano, and spend much (or all) of their career playing it.  Some don't.  Many developers learn to do SQL queries, and spend large parts (or all) of their careers doing them.  Some don't.  I think they're not only in the same league, they're a perfect comparison.

Comment: @MichaelShaw: Apparently you've never played the piano.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Leaping to conclusions about someone's musical experience by reading a sentence or two is not better than leaping to conclusions about someone's programming experience after a sentence or two.

Comment: @MichaelShaw: Right.  So you've never taken lessons then.  Had you done so, you'd understand exactly what I'm talking about.  What I'm *not* talking about is extensive knowledge of SQL, but basic, fundamental insight into a single keyword.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If you had a reason to think the two things were not a perfect comparison, I would think you'd have said what your point was by now instead of insinuating that you have a point.  If you have a reason to think pdr's comparison of SQL to piano playing is bad, I'd appreciate it if you would say what that reason is.

Comment: @MichaelShaw: What I am apparently not articulating well is this:  if I had a boss that I reported to that was the Systems Architect  for the enterprise application I was working on, but I found out that he didn't know the first thing about what a SQL JOIN statement meant, I would question his competence.

Comment: @MichaelShaw: As to a Lead Developer not knowing JOIN, I'm on the fence about that.  As Lewis Black once said about President Bush (whom he considered not well-travelled): "Even drunk and on a bet, you make it to Canada."